# JBoss AS 7.1 Virtual Hosts deployment

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, virtualhost

I have this working configuration:

jboss-web.xml (in WAR):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>java:/jaas/effebi</security-domain>
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

standalone.xml (in JBoss conf):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false" default-web-module="test">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="www.test.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

I need to deploy another app (e.g. www.foo.bar) at "/" context-root.

I read in the docs that I need to define virtual-host for having two simultaneous "/" root-contexts. So in jboss-web.xml:

```
<virtual-host>localhost</virtual-host>
<virtual-host>www.test.com</virtual-host>
```

This results in:

> JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
>         service jboss.web.host."www.test.com" (missing) dependents: [service jboss.web.deployment."www.test.com"./]
>
> 11:01:23,015 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner]
>   (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation
>   failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2"
>   => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.web.deployment.\"www.test.com\"./jboss.web.host.\"www.test.com\"Missing[jboss.web.deployment.\"www.test.com\"./jboss.web.host.\"www.test.com\"]"]}}}

Can somebody help me please? JBoss community hasn't been really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tag should point to virtual-server "name", not the domain. 
I blogged about that: http://fabiobozzo.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/multiple-web-applications-with-jboss-and-apache/